# PHP downloads at 0 bytes

Tags: php, download

I have ZIP files in a directory that is one step up from the root directory (to prevent hotlinking etc...). Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
    if(!$filename){
        header("Location: index.html");
    } else {
      function send_download($filename){
        $file_path = '../../../../downloads/' . $filename . '.zip';
        $file_size=@filesize($file_path);
        header("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Length: $file_size");
        readfile($file_path);
        exit;
    } 
    send_download($filename);
    }
    ?>
```

All the ZIP files are fine but using this method on an 'a' tag causes the downloads to be 0 bytes in file size! :(

Any ideas as to why?

Many thanks!

Comment: Either you path or filename wasn't found.

Comment: For sake of testing, use a full path to the file in filesize($file_path) and GET RID OF THAT HORRIBLE @ while testing! :)

Comment: You also shouldn't declare functions into an `if-then-else` statement

Comment: @Touki - except `if(!function_exists()) {...}`

Comment: Remove the @ before filesize, then update your question with the error message you'll get. Are you sure the path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the `Content-type` to the following:

```
Content-type: application/x-zip;
```

And before you do, check if the file exists.

```
<?php
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
    if(!$filename){
        header("Location: index.html");
    } else{
    function send_download($filename){
    $file_path = '../../../../downloads/' . $filename . '.zip';
    if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
    $file_size=@filesize($file_path);
    header("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Length: $file_size");
    readfile($file_path);
    exit;
    } 
    send_download($filename);
    }
    else
    die("Error 404!");
    }
?>
```

Comment: $filename won't contain the necessary path at the point you're doing it. it needs to be `file_exists($file_path)`.

Comment: Thanks guys, still no luck, I'm afraid :( Any further ideas?

Comment: I'm getting a blank screen :\

Comment: Do this. Put this in teh first line: `ini_set("display_errors", 1)` and say what you get.

Comment: Dude... Remove that `@` before `filesize` and in the `header`, give the `Content-type` as `text/plain` and let us know the output.

Comment: Still nothing, mate! This is mega confusing :(

Comment: What kinda server do you use. Give a small text `Hello World!` on the top of the page, and see if it is getting displayed!!! `:O`

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm using these guys: http://ukwebsolutionsdirect.co.uk/ - I can echo a "Hello World" okay! :)

Comment: Hey buddy, the `send_download($filename);` is after `exit`! What a blunder! Is that the issue???

Comment: Okay, I'm using this:
<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
    if(!$filename){
        header("Location: index.html");
    } else{
    function send_download($filename){
    $file_path = '../../../../downloads/' . $filename . '.zip';
 }
 if (file_exists($file_path))
    {
    $file_size=filesize($file_path);
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Length: $file_size");
    readfile($file_path);
 send_download($filename);
    exit;
 }
    else {
    die("Error 404!");
    }}
?>

Comment: @HedKandiMan Nice... That's good. So the file is not in the place where you are looking. May be remove one `../` and try?

Comment: Try removing one or two `../` and check na? May be your script path might be different? Just a guess... Trial and error right?

Comment: Right, this is the way I'm passing it: http://artists.platform-a.org.uk/axm/download.php?id=axm_-_visionary_eyes_(extended_mix)_-_24-bit - The zip files are two steps down (I have tried only using two ../../ but it still doesn't work).

Comment: Is there a file named `axm.zip`? Also, try echoing out `__dir__` and `__file__` so that you know if the address is correct.

Comment: All the filenames are correct, and I've tried echoing the values and nothing comes up for file_size or file_path but file_name comes up! :(

Comment: PLease update your question with all the relevant information. Using the comments for it keeps it from being useful to other people.

Comment: Apologies, George, I shall do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. header("Location: http://www.fqdn.tld/file.ext");
2. Based on _GET["id"] being > 0 and not null, you've created a function which has been used directly after, so you've just added more lines of code for no required purpose.
3. I see you have added an "@" sign as people have previously commented, however, the only way for you to begin fixing this is by:

   - Removing the @ sign as you should never use it, very bad practice, you should cater for all exceptions in your code, it makes for a really good programmer. (Scripting in PHP)
   - error_reporting(E_ALL);
   - Place point b) on it's own line but after the <?php - so we can see a full list of errors.
4. Your code is fine, the problem you have is permissions, ensure that apache has access to your "files" repository, the fact you are able to check that the file is there suggest slight permissions and the files exists, the point that 0 bytes are being returned suggest reading privileges are denied at Apache level.

Comment: Thank you Richard. How do I change the permissions? I use a shared host so this may be an issue.

Comment: If you use an FTP program, it is usually supported through the right click command to CHMOD it, and 755 will do just find. However, this may be where the problem exists anyways. I recommend putting your files in your root directory, but a misc subfolder name, eg: refer to the files as /g4445AF/fileid.zip

Comment: Thanks Richard, the permissions were already set at 755 for all and recursive subdirectories...

Comment: If you use SSH, great, then ps -aux is the command you want, get a list of active/established HTTP/Apache Web pages running, find the user and group running this, locate your file repository folder and on that folder, run chmod -R userName groupName

Comment: Although they may be 755, if Apache is trying to read files in another folder owned by different users and groups outside it's capable scope, it wouldn't read the files content. Example: PHP/SuExec runs the PHP scripts as the users name, example /home/develop/index.php would be owned by user: develop and group apache

Comment: I've done some edits for formatting, please see the help button in the editor (we use Markdown, which is extremely fun and easy to work with). To see what I did, just click the 'edit' link.

Answer (score 0):

Right, after a bit of Googling and some blood, sweat and tears I have finally found a solution!

```
<?php 
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
    header('Content-type: application/zip'); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    readfile('../../downloads/' . $filename . ".zip"); 
    exit;  
?>
```

Many thanks to all of whom shed some light on this!

Answer (score 0):

And here is the code with the filesize:

```
<?php 
    $filename = $_GET['id'];
    $file = "../../downloads/" . $filename . ".zip";
    header('Content-type: application/zip'); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $file); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
    readfile($file); 
    //echo filesize($file);
    exit;  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one mistake we all are doing check below.

> readfile($file); //$file should be relative not absolute. That's it.

Thanks,

Anirudh Sood.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, although I just solved this problem for myself. In my case it was the Content-Length header, I had:

```
header ('Content-Length: "'.$fileSize.'"');
```

Changing it to:

```
header ('Content-Length: '.$fileSize);
```

Solved it for me, PHP was trying to interpret the " but was fine with just the integer.